# Need to Fill empty cells with previous row value (Fill Down) in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

Need to replace Null into fill down value as you can see in **Need This** column I am using SQL Server 2019.

| Columns Right Now | Need This |
| --- | --- |
| Honda Civic | Honda Civic |
| Null | Honda Civic |
| Honda City | Honda City |
| Null | Honda City |
| Honda Accord | Honda Accord |
| Null | Honda Accord |
| Null | Honda Accord |
| Null | Honda Accord |

[Here Is The Actual Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVGX7.png)

Comment: Use [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: We need another column which provides the _grouping_ which you perceive to exist in the above table.